# how to show link "send to" in a Document library in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

how to show link "send to" in a Document library in Sharepoint 2010

Comment: Can you clarify your question? Do you mean that you want to add items to the send-to menu in a doc lib?
[Sample screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4PH1q.png)

Answer (score 1):

Struggled with this myself.  Firstly you have to setup the send to feature in CA - general application settings.

Its then a site feature you can enable - need to do that.

Then setup send to locations on the actual doc library under 'library settings' - 'advanced settings'